# php 554 SMTP synchronization error codeigniter on easyname.com and wamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, wamp

I am working with codeigniter 2.1.0 and I'm tryng to send an email with codeigniter method:

**_send_with_smtp()** witch is in Email.php class in \system\libraries\

and the reply i receive is:

**554 SMTP synchronization error.**

this issue occurs **both** in my **local WAMP** enviroment and in my online website on **easyname.com hosting**.

I don't know where to start to fix the problem, someone can help me?

Comment: Why don't you use email library?

Comment: Have you loaded your email library?

Comment: what do you mean for email library? i'm not calling it directly of course i use codeigniter standard for email sending but the error occurs in _send_with_smtp() method...

Comment: You should add your code. Then only we can check. `$this->load->library(email);`